# Constructing JSON string from Oracle DB

Tags: json, oracle

I have a Web application which gets it data from a JSON string.
The JSON is in the following format

```
{
    "contacts": [{
        "type": "contact",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "contact": 1,
        "links": ["Spouse", "Friends","Jane Doe","Harry Smith"]
                 }]
}
```

Now this is a sample data. My actual DB is in Oracle. My question would be how do I construct this JSON from Oracle.

Comment: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2382829

Comment: http://technology.amis.nl/2011/06/14/creating-json-document-straight-from-sql-query-using-listagg-and-with-clause/

Comment: With `||` operator. Just leave alone formatting JSON and concentrate on feeding data. If you post your data structure (the tables you want this data to generate from), and show us what have you already tried, we may tell you how to actually do it.

Comment: This might be helful https://code.google.com/p/plsql-utils/ and look for title **Generate JSON using PL/SQL** and **Parse JSON using PL/SQL**

Comment: @Polppan, You got it right... I do need a PL/SQL procedure. does anybody know how i can contruc this?

Comment: @AnaMaria Please provide sample data table and structure for what you are looking to generate as JSON.

Comment: There is also the [PL/JSON library on GitHub](https://github.com/pljson/pljson)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the best method I've come across: http://ora-00001.blogspot.sk/2010/02/ref-cursor-to-json.html.

To summarise:

- Use the `DBMS_XMLGEN` package to generate XML from a `SYS_REFCURSOR`.
- Then transform it using this [XSLT](https://github.com/doekman/xml2json-xslt).

I like it because there's no manual generation and because you have the option of returning XML too by skipping the final transformation.

Comment: Please include the relevant items from your link in your answer, as well as explanations for them. Should that site ever change or be deleted your accepted answer becomes useless to future viewers.

Comment: This may be the only way but it has to be said that it's not a very sustainable way. JSON is a far more light-weight markup than XML. This answer is basically saying that nobody has made a solution public for programatically presenting oracle data in the world's favourite API format.

Comment: That is factually incorrect. The answer is what provides a public, programmatical solution for presenting Oracle data in the worlds favourite API format.

If you have a better answer post it and get it voted on. Down-voting for no better reason than not liking the particular solution defies sense.